# ArrayList<HashMap<String, String> working with Cloud Endpoints?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I use java to program an API with Google Cloud Endpoints and the Datastore. I just added a `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` as a field of one of my entities but it seems not to be recognized by Cloud Endpoints. I use the Objectify framework.

At first I noticed some NullPointerException occuring because of it and then I saw that the field isn't even mentionned by the Datastore Viewer.

Is this type not supported by the datastore?

Comment: ...Why do you need a list of maps? This has nothing to do with your actual question, but I'm curious.

Comment: There is a small game in my app so I need to store a list of Map, each Map representing a player (with three key/value pairs: name, id and score)

Comment: It seems like that's a job more suited to a special `Player` object, rather than a map. I'd assume that Google has support for custom objects, though admittedly I'm not certain about that. If not, ignore me.

Comment: Please include the stack trace of the exception you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field should be supported, both by datastore and the cloud endpoints marshaller. Just bear in mind that **empty collections are stored as null values on the datastore**.

You'll have to init the collection upon retrieval in case the entity was stored with an empty collection.

Having said that I Agree with @QPaysTaxes recommendation, in the long run you'll save yourself a lot of pain if you wrap that into a POJO. Which BTW can be referenced by ID instead of having to duplicate data all over the place.

Comment: Yes it is supported, it seems that I wasn't initializing the field correctly. And yes the POJO solution suggested by @QPaysTaxes is a better idea than Map, so I have implemented it. Thanks to both of you

Answer (score 0):

With Objectify you can store any POJO, can you check that the field appears by using the developer's console?

By the way, a Cloud Endpoint can return any object (but not a primitive one, like *int* or *boolean*). So it won't be a problem on that matter.

Comment: I checked both the new developer console and the old one and each field appears except this one. While it's a relief that you said it is possible, I am still wondering what's going on.